# Cross browser adding row to table- JQuery?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, row

Does anyone know a good way to dynamically add a row to a table in jQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically for a cross browser implementation you should do $('table tbody').append("Foo")

Since IE doesn't automatically add the tbody for you but other browsers do.

Comment: Won't this add a foo for each tbody in the table?

Comment: There's USUALLY only one tbody per table. But if you have multiple yes, this won't work. I believe the link Luwe goes into more possibilities and cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('table').append('<tr><td>Foo</td></tr>');
```

Comment: use table_id instead of table. If a page contains more then one table then it will create problem.